# & Bit operation in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

In doing a bitwise `&`, I thought by specifying the digit it would add that digit in the necessary spot, but in python I get the following:

```
>>> 4&2
0

>>> 4&1<<1
0

>>> 0b100 & 0b010
0
```

I thought that this would give `110` or 6, but it seems like either I'm misunderstanding the `&` operator. What am I doing wrong here or misunderstanding in the above?

Comment: You want bitwise or '|' to give you 0b110 or 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitwise `&` gives you a 1 in a bit position only if all operands have a 1 in that position. You are looking for bitwise `|`.

Comment: thank you. How would you refer to a 'bit position'? Is it usually called the "1's", "2s", "4s" ? Or 1st, 2nd, 3rd lsb, or how is it usually referred to?

Comment: You read bits from right to left. The number at the right end is the least important bit, 0b0101 would be = 1*1 + 0*2 + 1*4 + 0*8

Comment: @sergenp got it, so in the above would you say "there is a one in the one's position, a 0 in the two's position", or or how you directly reference where the bit is?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 1st lsb 2nd lsb...(LSB0, LSB1...) is one of the ways you can say it, as you can say 1st msb 2nd msb... (MSB0, MSB1...)